# How can download file from FTP server with some extension in VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net

I want to download the some file on remote location from FTP protocol, that have any extentions. For example I want to download the all file from remote site *.pdf, *.txt . So I have build this code in Visual Basic.

```
Public Function GetFiles() As Generic.List(Of String)
Dim fileList As New Generic.List(Of String)

Select Case _config.Protocol
    Case FTPConfiguration.FTPProtocol.FTP

    Dim objFTPRequest As FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_config.FTPUrl & _config.MonitorDirectory)), FtpWebRequest)
    objFTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(_config.FTPUsername, _config.FTPPassword)
    objFTPRequest.KeepAlive = False
    objFTPRequest.UsePassive = False
    objFTPRequest.UseBinary = True
    objFTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory



    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(objFTPRequest.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
    Using respStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(objFTPRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Dim line As String = respStream.ReadLine()
        While line IsNot Nothing

        If line Like _config.FileSearch Then
            fileList.Add(line)

        End If

        line = respStream.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using

End Select

For Each fileName As String In fileList
    Me.DownloadFile(fileName)
Next

Return fileList
End Function
```

How you can see, I have write this line to find the File but not works:

```
If line Like _config.FileSearch Then
```

I use LIKE operator but I think that this is not the corret way to fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `line.EndsWith(".pdf")` to check if the file ends with that extension.

If you want to use `like`, the `_config.FileSearch` must be `"*.pdf"`.

```
If line Like "*.pdf" Then
   Console.WriteLine(line)   
End If
```

You can also use [Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
If Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*\.(pdf|doc|txt|zip)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
   Console.WriteLine(line)
End If
```

Refer [String.EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_3) and [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx)

Comment: ok but I wanto to search all txt file and all pdf file? but I must insert this extension file in one String.
For example _config.FileSearch = " '*.txt', '*.zip', 'aaa_*.zip' " ?